# Interference of counter propagating beams

Tags: optics, interference

I am trying to build an optical system where a thin glass plate is illuminated by two mutually coherent beams  E1 and E2 (sketch is below).
My question is: 
Do I get an interference pattern on the glass surface where the two beams overlap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You asked if you will get an interference pattern *on the surface of the glass*.  Assuming no reflection at the surfaces, the answer is "no" if the two beams are collimated and perpendicular to the glass surfaces, because the phase and amplitude distribution will be uniform along both surfaces.  However, you will get an interference pattern *inside the glass* consisting of Bragg planes parallel to the glass surfaces.  There will also be an interference pattern consisting of Bragg planes *outside* the glass in the overlapped counterpropagating beams on both sides of the plate.

Again assuming no reflections, if the glass plate is tilted the plate will be tilted relative to the Bragg planes, and the Bragg planes will intersect the surfaces of the plate.  In this case, there will be an interference pattern on the surfaces, corresponding to the pattern formed by the intersections of Bragg planes with the surface.

When reflections are included, it gets more complicated, because you end up with a lot of beams superimposed and interfering.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am interested in forming an interference pattern inside glass using low coherence light (coherence length 10-20um) so that interference fringes exist only within very thin slice inside glass or wherever optical paths of both beams are equal. Sounds to me that the best way is to try experimentally as it looks there are no violations of physical laws. Am i right?

Comment: You are right.  What you want to do is possible, but of course you will need to adjust the path lengths in your setup very csrefully.  It would also be a good idea to use glass with antireflection coatings on both surfaces.  If you don't need the fringes spaced a half wavelength apare (inside the plate), then your beams can be incident at Brewster's angle to nearly eliminate reflections.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will observe an interference pattern providing that the reflection effects are small in comparison with penetration ones. For example, when one side of the glass is covered with a photo-sensitive material (photo-plate).

For a true interference at a point $x$ you must have a sum of two different waves at the same time; only then the total intensity will have an interference addenda.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand that. My concern is that the waves have opposite Pointing (? - had my University course ages ago) vector and thus they carry energy in opposite directions. Would it preclude formation of interference pattern?

Comment: Normally no, they are equivalent in the process of chemical transformation of a photo-sensitive molecule. What counts is the field strength, not its "direction".

Comment: If you count photon by photon ( a low intensity beam), it is their frequency (energy $\hbar\omega$) who provoques chemical irreversible reactions; the momentum transfer $q\propto\omega/c$ is negligible for that.

Comment: That sounds encouraging, thanks. Will test it experimentally then.

Comment: @YDFA Could you test it?